# Read objects in many-to-many relationship in Realm?

Tags: android, realm

I am performing many to many relationship in Realm and i am trying to read objects in Realm but i ain't getting Realm Results. This is how i'm storing objects in Realm.

```
fun addMessage(message : Message?,ref_id : String?){
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().use {realm ->
        realm.executeTransaction {realm ->
            val num = realm.where<Messages>().max("auto_index")
            var nextVal : Int ?= null
            if (num == null){
                nextVal = 1
            }else{
                nextVal = num.toInt() + 1
            }
            val msg = Messages()
            msg.messageId = message?.message_uid
            msg.body = message?.body
            msg.isCheck = message?.isCheck
            msg.auto_index = nextVal

            val messa = realm.where<MessageRef>().equalTo("messageRefId",ref_id).findFirst()
            if (messa != null){
                messa.messages?.add(msg)
            }
            else {
                val messageRef = MessageRef()
                messageRef.messageRefId = ref_id
                messageRef.messages = RealmList<Messages>()
                messageRef.messages?.add(msg)
              realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(messageRef)
            }
           realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

That's how i'm reading objects from database.

```
   fun getAllMessages (realm : Realm?,messageRefId : String?)=
    realm?.where<MessageRef>()?.equalTo("messageRefId",messageRefId)?.findFirst()
            ?.messages?.sort("auto_index")
```

}

Below is my MessageRef model.

```
open class MessageRef : RealmObject() {
@Required
@PrimaryKey
var messageRefId : String ?= null

var messages : RealmList<Messages> ?= null
}
```

Below is my Messages Model.

```
open class Messages : RealmObject(){
@Required
@PrimaryKey
var messageId : String ?= null

@Required
var auto_index : Int ?= null

@Required
var body : String ?= null

@Required
var isCheck : String ?= null
}
```

But I'm not getting any results. I debug the code and found that objects are successfully storing but not able to read.Below is my activity code.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_chat_page)
    initialize()
    message_ref_id = intent?.getStringExtra("conversation_id")
    toolbar_name?.text = name
    messageList = realmMessageController?.getAllMessages(realm,message_ref_id)
}
```

Please tell me anybody why i ain't getting result.

Comment: `import io.realm.kotlin.createObject` can make `realm.createObject<MessageRef>()` but consider adding the exception message so we know what goes wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can use `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` to get managed proxy, do `if(!list.contains(managedProxy))` and only add to list in the `if`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me . Now i am able to store objects but getting issue in reading objects. I edited my code, please take a look and suggest me where is the problem. Thankyou :)

Comment: Please show Messages and MessageRef realm object model classes

Comment: I edited my code now. check it out.

Comment: use linkingobjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORIGINAL ANSWER: You are getting the following error

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'value' is not a valid managed object
```

And that's because you're trying to add an unmanaged object to a managed RealmObject's RealmList

You can use `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` to get a managed proxy of the thing you are saving:

```
messageRef.messages?.add(realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Messages().apply {
    messageId = message?.message_uid
    isCheck = message?.isCheck
    auto_index = nextValue
}))
```

---

EDIT: to do what you want, you just need to check against the managed RealmObject if it's already in the list.

```
val managed = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Messages().apply {
    messageId = message?.message_uid
    isCheck = message?.isCheck
    auto_index = nextValue
})
if(messageRef.messages?.contains(managed) == false) {
    messageRef.messages?.add(managed)
}
```

---

EDIT2: For your query, you need

```
open class Messages : RealmObject(){
    @Required
    @PrimaryKey
    var messageId : String ?= null

    @Required
    var auto_index : Int ?= null

    @Required
    var body : String ?= null

    @Required
    var isCheck : String ?= null
    }

    @field:LinkingObjects("messages")
    val messageRefs : RealmResults<MessageRef>? = null
```

Then

```
realm.where<Messages>()
     .equalTo("messageRefs.messageRefId", messageRefId)
     .sort("auto_index")
     .findAll()
```

Comment: Hey, I edited my code , Please tell me any solution.

Comment: Thankyou so much , it works.. Also i wanna ask why you used "messageRefs.messageRefId" here. why simply i can't use message Ref id and get the objects of MessageRef class then fetch all messages from list which are linked to that messageRefId.

Comment: How can i read all messages in background thread, I have used findAllAsync() but its not working.

Comment: Use `findAll()` if you are  on background thread. But `findAllAsync()` also works if you use RealmChangeListener and you keep the RealmResults as a field

Comment: Thanks it worked. Thank you so much for suggesting me.